# Интерактивное меню в консоли (Windows + Linux)

Tags: golang

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь сделать простое консольное меню, интерактивно реагирующее на нажатие клавиши выбора пункта меню. Например меню:

```
1) пункт 1;
2) пункт 2;
0) выход.
```

Для выбора пункта нужно однократно нажать клавишу, например "1" и меню должно отработать. Так же в некоторых случаях нужно отрабатывать управляющие клавиши, тип Enter, Esc, Up и т.п.
Если в Windows получилось сделать без особых проблем, используя конструкцию:

```
//#include <conio.h>
import "C"

func GetCh() int {
    c := C.getch() // C.int
    return int(c)
}
```

... здесь управляющие клавиши легко отлавливаются через проверку первого байта 0x00 или 0xE0.

В Linux столкнулся с проблемами. Использовал код:

```
/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
char getch(){
    char ch = 0;
    struct termios old = {0};
    fflush(stdout);
    if( tcgetattr(0, &old) &lt; 0 ) perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    if( tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) &lt; 0 ) perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if( read(0, &ch,1) &lt; 0 ) perror("read()");
    old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    if(tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) &lt; 0) perror("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
    return ch;
}
*/
import "C"

func GetCh() int {
     c := C.getch()  // C.int
     return int(c)
}
```

Проблемы возникают при нажатии на управляющие клавиши. Во-первых их тяжело отследить, потому что первым байтом идёт ESC, который соответствует коду нажатой клавиши ESC. В вторых, нажатие клавиш может состоять из произвольного количества последовательности. Здесь нужно создавать из них простыни таблиц соответствия, что не является моей задачей.
Попытка использования сторонних модулей не помогла:

github.com/nsf/termbox-go - после обязательного Init очищает консоль, что мне категорически не нужно;
github.com/rthornton128/goncurses - так и не получилось до конца установить в Windows, но и он не работает с UTF, что мне важно для других задач;
github.com/eiannone/keyboard  - почти подошёл, но некорректно обрабатывает клавиши Вверх Вниз если работать через keyboard.GetKey(). Через keyboard.GetSingleKey() - начинает дублировать коды клавиш после их нескольких нажатий, пока не вылетает по ошибке "panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range":

```
for {
    ch, key, err := keyboard.GetSingleKey()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", ch, key)
}
```

В принципе, если бы в Linux удалось получить сразу весь набор байтов введёны при нажатии клавиш - этого бы было достаточно (или проверку пустоты буфера клавиатуры), но найти как это сделать в Go не удалось.

В общем вопрос можно сузить до последнего абзаца - как получить весь набор байтов нажатой клавиши в Linux, или каким сторонним инструментом можно для этого воспользоваться (понимаю, что инструменты есть, но не могу их найти... или не понимаю как это сделать)? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуй https://github.com/peterh/liner

Comment: Ivan Black, спасибо, но удалось решить проблему в пакете https://github.com/eiannone/keyboard которым пока удовлетворён.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, пообщавшись с автором пакета https://github.com/eiannone/keyboard все проблемы удалось решить для платформ Windows и Linux.

Ожидать нажатие клавиши:

```
for {
    ch, key, err := keyboard.GetSingleKey()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", ch, key)
}
```

Описание кодов клавиш для разных платформ есть в самом пакете.